# LinkedIn autofill duplicate buttons

Tags: linkedin-api, autofill

I am implementing LinkedIn auto fill button on my registration form page. But when I add the script it adds 2 buttons into it. I have checked if there is multiple scripts added on the page, but that is not the case. Both the buttons work absolutely fine. But I dont want that second button. Attached is screenshot.

Any one who came across same problem?

[image]

Comment: I am facing same problem, but two buttons are coming for me, for two forms, three buttons for three forms. But all buttons are coming on first form itself as shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

If you include the autofill.js script twice on the page it will render two buttons.

View page source and look for multiple:
    script src="https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/js/autofill.js" 
    type="text/javascript" async>

Get rid of all but one.